# What is the alternate for document.all.item(Id,0) javascript

Tags: javascript

I need an alternate solution for `document.all.item(id,0)`. Its working fine in windows7 IE browser but as per IE they have mention that it will not support for `IE11` browser so kindly any one help me to sort this issue.

**See code below:**

```
function displayById(id){
    var tid = document.all.item(id,0);
    tid.style.display ='inline';
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(id)`.

Comment: You were a Google away from "How to get an element by ID"?!

Comment: You can also use `document.querySelector("#id")`. Note that there should be `#` before the id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried document.getElementById() but some time i got  multiple id's with same name so it is not working properly and this javascript function is a common for most of the pages so i cant make a correction in the id .

Comment: @PhaniKumarM in my case i got  two elements with same id that's why they have used document.all.item(id,0) as 0th index. so in querySelector is it possible to use 0th index to get the exact element value

Comment: You should fix your HTML. All HTML elements should have unique `id`. If you want to retrieve multiple elements then use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM yes but my application is more than a decade old and it has 500 plus jsp files so its some what hard to find in some cases id's are generated dynamically. so is there any other solution possible .

Comment: @Shimaan Do you mind updating your question with sample elements having same id's. It will give better picture.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById(id);` should achieve the result you're looking for. This will get the HTML element with the id of `id`